# how Count field using django orm

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Hi Everyone i trying to count  active and inactive status sepratally, below mention code to count all, i need to count active and inactive status sepratally,pls help me out. pls refere sample data

```
Type.objects.all().aggregate(Count('status'))

output=5
```

[image: table formet]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at https://pythonguides.com/python-django-group-by/

```
Type.objects.values('status').annotate(
    status_count=Count('id')
).values(
    'status', 'status_count'
).order_by()
```

EDIT: count only in active status

```
Type.objects.filter(status='active').aggregate(
    active_count=Count('status')
).values('active_count')
```

Comment: how will count Active status ? pls refere sample data also